# Computing configuration for nvidia geforce rtx 2080 ti

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, distributed-computing, computing-environment

I am trying to build a small station with nvidia GeForce RTX 2080 TI which can be used to perform AI computing related study and practice.

I installed the CUDA driver. However, I have below problems:

1. I cannot use "nvidia-smi" to see the GPU info which includes the number of CUDA cores, etc. Below is what I got after running this command.

   [image]
2. I tried to run PySpark to read sample data using CUDA cores. However, I do not know whether the PySpark REALLY call CUDA cores or not. I run "nvidia-smi -l" and get same above output. Below is the PySpark commands:

   ```
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    os.environ['JAVA_HOME']='/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.282.b08-1.el7_9.x86_64'

    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example")\
        .config("spark.executorEnv.CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES", "0,1")\
        .config("spark.executorEnv.cores_per_device", "1024")\
        .config("spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.maxNumRows", "500")\
        .config("spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.maxNumCols", "500")\
    .getOrCreate()

    dirs = "/data_dir/domestic/common_data/CONTACT_SUMMARY_PERSIST.9989.parquet"
    df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "|").parquet(dirs)
   ```

Any help and advice would be highly appreciated.